# Json format error in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I'm getting the error below from my cloud formation template. It happens when using json and pure yaml.

#### error

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: JSON not well-formed. at Line: 13, Column: 10 (Service: Ssm, Status Code: 400,
```

#### template with json

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "AWS CloudFormation Template for Response Plans"
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
  Domain:
    Type: String
  Team:
    Type: String
  NotificationARN:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn
Resources:
  UpdateAliasResponsePlan:
    Type: AWS::SSMIncidents::ResponsePlan
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - SsmAutomation:
            RoleArn: !Ref Role
            DocumentName: UpdateAliasDocument
            # ActionType: UpdateAlias
      DisplayName: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      # Engagements:
      #   Engagements
      IncidentTemplate:
        Impact: 3
        NotificationTargets:
          - SnsTopicArn:
              Ref: NotificationARN
        Summary: "String"
        Title: "String"
      Name: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Team"
          Value: !Ref Team
        - Key: "Domain"
          Value: !Ref Domain
        - Key: "Environment"
          Value: !Ref Environment
  UpdateAliasDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      Content: |
        {
          "schemaVersion": "2.2",
          "parameters": {
            "Environment": { "type": "string"},
            "Domain": { "type": "string"},
            "Team": { "type": "string"},
            "NotificationARN": { "type": "string", "default": "/sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn"}
          },
          "mainSteps": [
            { "action": "aws:runShellScript",
              "name": "runCommands",
              "inputs": {
                "runCommand": ["aws lambda update-functionconfiguration --function-name $FunctionArn --version $FunctionVersion"]
            }
          ]
        }
  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: UpdateAliasPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${Environment}-*
```

#### template with yaml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "AWS CloudFormation Template for Response Plans"
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
  Domain:
    Type: String
  Team:
    Type: String
  NotificationARN:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn
Resources:
  UpdateAliasResponsePlan:
    Type: AWS::SSMIncidents::ResponsePlan
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - SsmAutomation:
            RoleArn: !Ref Role
            DocumentName: UpdateAliasDocument
            # ActionType: UpdateAlias
      DisplayName: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      # Engagements:
      #   Engagements
      IncidentTemplate:
        Impact: 3
        NotificationTargets:
          - SnsTopicArn:
              Ref: NotificationARN
        Summary: "String"
        Title: "String"
      Name: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Team"
          Value: !Ref Team
        - Key: "Domain"
          Value: !Ref Domain
        - Key: "Environment"
          Value: !Ref Environment
  UpdateAliasDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        parameters:
          - name: FunctionVersion
            type: "String"
            defaultValue: "1"
          - name: FunctionArn
            type: "String"
        mainSteps:
          - action: aws:runShellScript
            name: "runCommand"
            inputs:
              runCommand: "aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $FunctionArn --version $FunctionVersion"
  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: UpdateAliasPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${Environment}-*
```

#### Another YAML Version

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "AWS CloudFormation Template for Response Plans"
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
  Domain:
    Type: String
  Team:
    Type: String
  NotificationARN:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn
Resources:
  UpdateAliasResponsePlan:
    Type: AWS::SSMIncidents::ResponsePlan
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - SsmAutomation:
            RoleArn: !Ref Role
            DocumentName: UpdateAliasDocument
            # ActionType: UpdateAlias
      DisplayName: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      # Engagements:
      #   Engagements
      IncidentTemplate:
        Impact: 3
        NotificationTargets:
          - SnsTopicArn:
              Ref: NotificationARN
        Summary: "String"
        Title: "String"
      Name: "UpdateLambdaAlias"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Team"
          Value: !Ref Team
        - Key: "Domain"
          Value: !Ref Domain
        - Key: "Environment"
          Value: !Ref Environment
  UpdateAliasDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        parameters:
          - name: FunctionVersion
            type: "String"
            defaultValue: "1"
          - name: FunctionName
            type: "String"
        mainSteps:
          - name: UpdateLambdaAlias
            action: aws:executeAWSApi
            inputs:
              Service: "lambda"
              Api: UpdateFunctionConfiguration
              FunctionName: $FunctionName
              FunctionVersion: $FunctionVersion
  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: UpdateAliasPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${Environment}-*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the way I was defining the parameters. I needed to remove the name key.

#### replace

```yaml
 UpdateAliasDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        parameters:
          - name: FunctionVersion
            type: "String"
            defaultValue: "1"
          - name: FunctionName
            type: "String"
        mainSteps:
          - name: UpdateLambdaAlias
            action: aws:executeAWSApi
            inputs:
              Service: "lambda"
              Api: UpdateFunctionConfiguration
              FunctionName: $FunctionName
              FunctionVersion: $FunctionVersion
```

#### with

```yaml
 UpdateAliasDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        parameters:
          FunctionVersion
            type: "String"
            defaultValue: "1"
          FunctionName
            type: "String"
        mainSteps:
          - name: UpdateLambdaAlias
            action: aws:executeAWSApi
            inputs:
              Service: "lambda"
              Api: UpdateFunctionConfiguration
              FunctionName: $FunctionName
              FunctionVersion: $FunctionVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error when it tries to resolve the SSM parameters.  It is a 400 error, so it may be that you don't have permission to retrieve the parameter from SSM.  In this case it is looking for `/sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn` so verify that the account you are using to create the stack has permission to retrieve that parameter.  [This article](https://cloudkatha.com/using-ssm-parameter-in-cloudformation-here-is-the-right-way/) shows the permissions needed.

If so, also verify that the value of that parameter in SSM would result in a valid template if you pasted it into your template.  Verify that the [SSM parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) is of type `String`, as `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>` is

> A Systems Manager parameter whose value is a string. This corresponds
> to the String parameter type in Parameter Store.

That link also mentions the following and gives an alternative if you are want to fetch a secure string:

> AWS CloudFormation does not support defining template parameters as
> SecureString Systems Manager parameter types.

Also, it may be that you need to format the default to not start with a slash.  [This page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) shows an example that does not start with a slash, or for hierarchical parameters that do begin with a slash, it may need to be in single quotes (Example 2 shows it that way)

Comment: I need to add those permissions to the role I've defined in the template or somewhere else?

Comment: I mean to your own user account (assuming you are the one creating the stack).  Are you able to view the value of the parameter  in SSM Parameter Store?  Is it a String parameter?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html

Comment: I am able to see it and it is a string

Comment: That should confirm it satisfies the [requirement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types) that "If a specified parameter doesn't exist in Parameter Store under the caller's AWS account, AWS CloudFormation returns a validation error. "  Are you using the default value, or passing in a different parameter at creation time?

Comment: It could be that you should not start with a / for the default.  I saw another example here that shows a default with no slash or within single quotes: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: I'm using the default value

Comment: Looks like the `/` is required. I get the error `Unable to fetch parameters [sandbox06/Topics/PolicyData/arn] from parameter store for this account.` without it.